# Align image columns by max value

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have an image where I would like to offset each column so that the maximum value of each column is vertically centered in the image. Here's some toy data:

```
unaligned = np.array([[0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0],
                      [0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,0],
                      [0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0],
                      [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0]]).T
```

[image]

Once aligned, it should look like

```
aligned = np.array([[0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0],
                    [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0]]).T
```

[image]

I could go column by column, find the index of the maximum value, then rewrite the column to a new array with the maximum value at the midpoint. But is there a concise (and faster) way to do this, especially if I have images with thousands of columns? Perhaps even some image processing routine with the column max values used as control points?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the nested calls to `np.array`. Just nested lists like `np.array([[0,1,...], [...], [...]])` will work fine.

Comment: You could at least vectorize the finding of the maximum into a single operation. Since each column will require a different shift, you may have to use a loop for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
m,n = unaligned.shape
col_shifts = m//2 - unaligned.argmax(0)
row_idx = np.mod(np.arange(m)[:,None]-col_shifts,m)
aligned_out = unaligned[row_idx,np.arange(n)]
```

If you are trying to fill the shifted in positions with zeros and the ends of the columns are zeros, we can alternatively get `row_idx` with `clipping`, like so -

```
row_idx = (np.arange(m)[:,None]-col_shifts).clip(min=0,max=m-1)
```

Comment: This is changing the values in the columns though. Ideally, the column data should just be shifted into alignment.

Comment: @JoeFlip I am not sure what you mean by that. This is just getting new row indices and thus shifting each column. Try the second approach with `clipping` too.

Comment: @ Divakar Oh, I'm sorry! I had a typo. Yes it works just fine. Thanks!